# Compare two CSV files and print the rows that are different Python

Tags: python, csv, compare, diff, with-statement

I'm trying to compare two csv files that are like below

```
English.csv
i
am
is
was
were

Dictionary.csv
i,insomnia
d,disease
bc,breast cancer
```

I'm trying to compare the first columns in two files and print the rows that are different from Dictionary.csv like below

```
final.csv
d,disease
bc,breast cancer
```

I tried this code.

```
import csv
with open('English.csv', 'rb') as csvfile1:
    with open ("Dictionary.csv", "rb") as csvfile2:
        reader1 = csv.reader(csvfile1)
        reader2 = csv.reader(csvfile2)
        rows1 = [row for row in reader1]
        rows2 = [row for row in reader2]
        col_a = [row1[0] for row1 in rows1]
        col_b = [row2[0] for row2 in rows2]
        col_c = [row2[1] for row2 in rows2]
        only_b = [text for text in col_b if not text in col_a]
```

I can get data from first column that is different, but not from the second column like below. How can I get the corresponding data from second column?

```
>>>only_b
['d','bc']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how effective is this but IMO does what you want:

```
import csv
with open('English.csv', 'rb') as csvfile1:
    with open ("Dictionary.csv", "rb") as csvfile2:
        reader1 = csv.reader(csvfile1)
        reader2 = csv.reader(csvfile2)
        rows1_col_a = [row[0] for row in reader1]
        rows2 = [row for row in reader2]
        only_b = []
        for row in rows2:
            if row[0] not in rows1_col_a:
                only_b.append(row)
        print only_b
```

Outputs:

```
[['d', 'disease'], ['bc', 'breast cancer']]
```